# Run promises sequentially in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, sequential

I'm still figuring node.js and promises out.

There's an area in my code where I would like my sql statements to run sequentially.

I would like one sql statement to run once one sql statement is done. I'm not sure if I am implementing promises properly.

**one of the sql statements:**

```
 var selectbotagentstoadd=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        var sql='SELECT tbltestbotagentstoadd.AgentID FROM tbltestbotagentstoadd WHERE tbltestbotagentstoadd.IDNumber=? AND tbltestbotagentstoadd.MSISDN=?;'
        DB.query(sql,[agentidpassnum,agentnumber],function(err,results){
            if (err){
                    return reject(err);
            }; 
            return resolve(results);
        });
       })
```

**the promise statement:**

```
await insertbotagentstoadd.then(()=>{
   console.log("done with one");
})
.then(()=>{ selectbotagentstoadd.then((results)=>
{
        AgenttoaddIDStore=[];
       results.forEach(agent=>{
          AgenttoaddIDStore.push({
           AgentID:agent.AgentID
       });
        ctx.session.tempAgentID=agent.AgentID
       });
console.log("agent ID: "+ctx.session.tempAgentID);
console.log("done with two");
})})
.then((results)=>{insertcctblricaagents
console.log("done with three");
})
.then((results)=>{selectcctblricaagents.then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
            AgentnewIDStore=[];
            result.forEach(agent=>{
                AgentnewIDStore.push({
                AgentID:agent.AgentID
            })
            ctx.session.AgentID=agent.AgentID
            })
            console.log("cctblricaagents agent ID: "+ ctx.session.AgentID);
            console.log("done with four");
})})
.then(insertcctblricaagentsnum.then((result)=>{
console.log("done with five");
}))
.then(selectcctblricaagentsnum.then((result)=>{
    console.log(result)
    AgentIDStore=[];
    result.forEach(agent=>{
    AgentIDStore.push({
        AgentID:agent.AgentID,
        MainNumber:agent.MainNumber,
    })
    ctx.session.AgentID=agent.AgentID
    ctx.session.agentnumber=agent.MainNumber
    })
    console.log("cctblricaagentsnum agent ID: "+ ctx.session.AgentID);
    console.log("done with six");
}))
.then(insertcctblintblbotagents.then((result)=>{
    console.log("done with seven");
}));
```

**The results I get from the terminal:**

```
Agent number: 27815567777
done with one
done with three
agent ID: 89
done with two
[]
cctblricaagents agent ID: null
done with four
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you properly return the promises in each of the `then` blocks, it should execute sequentially.

simplifying your code, for ex:

```js
await insertbotagentstoadd
  .then(() => {
    console.log("done with one");
  })
  .then(() => selectbotagentstoadd)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with two");
    return res;
  })
  .then((results) => insertcctblricaagents)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with three");
    return res;
  })
  .then((results) => selectcctblricaagents)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with four");
    return res;
  })
  .then(() => insertcctblricaagentsnum)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with five");
    return res;
  })
  .then(() => selectcctblricaagentsnum)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with six");
    return res;
  })
  .then(() => insertcctblintblbotagents)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with seven");
    return res;
  });
```

Edit:

How it will look with your calculation included:

```js
await insertbotagentstoadd
  .then(() => {
    console.log("done with one");
  })
  .then(() => selectbotagentstoadd)
  .then((results) => {
    AgenttoaddIDStore = [];
    results.forEach((agent) => {
      AgenttoaddIDStore.push({
        AgentID: agent.AgentID,
      });
      ctx.session.tempAgentID = agent.AgentID;
    });
    return AgenttoaddIDStore;
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with two");
    return res;
  })
  .then((results) => insertcctblricaagents)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with three");
    return res;
  })
  .then((results) => selectcctblricaagents)
  .then((result) => {
    AgentnewIDStore = [];
    result.forEach((agent) => {
      AgentnewIDStore.push({
        AgentID: agent.AgentID,
      });
      ctx.session.AgentID = agent.AgentID;
    });
    return AgentnewIDStore;
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("done with four");
    return res;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. For clarity does res mean results? What happens to the area of code where I'm trying to store query results in an array?

This code: 
 AgenttoaddIDStore=[];
       results.forEach(agent=>{
          AgenttoaddIDStore.push({
           AgentID:agent.AgentID
       });
        ctx.session.tempAgentID=agent.AgentID
       });

Comment: yes. res is just short for result. i have removed your code so it is easier to read the code. you can add it back on when you implement it. the only thing necessary is to return the promise in each block. in my case, since i dont have braces around the function body, it will auto return the promise, in your case you need to explicitly say `() => {return selectbotagentstoadd.then(...)}`, and it should work

Comment: I've tried it and it works! Thank you so much!! :D